# Page switching script issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is this my first stack overflow post so I hope I will fullfill the requirements of a good topic. But, I'm french so I apologize if some things are not explained properly.

Just to let you know, I'm pretty new to web development. I've started a few months ago by learning basics of html ccs JavaScript (+JQuery) for a month beside of my job. Then, I've started to develop a website for 2 twitch streamers  (with little viewer average). Here is the link if you want to check (so you will be able to see the issue I'm talking about): ponceriv.fr

Has the website is quite light, I've decided to make a "monopage" structure as I'm using a single html file (index.html) and I use Jquery to manipulate the DOM in order to switch pages.

Here is a part of the script (you can directly check in the core-handler.js) :

```
// When the user clicks on a nav button
$('.nav-item-container').click(function () {
    //remove the Nav-active class from nav button previously active
    $('.nav-item-container').removeClass('nav-active');
....
....
    // the clicked nav button is the second one
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'nav-item-container-2') {
        // the new active page is the second one / the "about" page
        let $newActiveWrapper = $('.about-wrapper');
        // the nav button that will have the active design
        let $toActiveNav = $('#nav-item-container-2');
        // Check if this page is already active
        if ($activeWrapper.attr('id') == $newActiveWrapper.attr('id')) {
            // re-set the class nav-active on the same button (I know, this is not optimal)
            $toActiveNav.addClass('nav-active');
            // If not already active
        } else {
            // The nav button get the 
            $toActiveNav.addClass('nav-active');
            // Prepare the css properties for the "enter" animation of the new page
            $newActiveWrapper.css({
                opacity: '0',
                position: 'relative',
                top: '100px',
                left: '0'
            });

            // Hide overflow because the animation makes scrollbar visible
            $('#content').css({
                'overflow': 'hidden'
            });

            // Check if the page is a secondary content (=/= stream player page) so we'll make the mini twitch player display
            if ($('.secondary-content').css('display') == 'none') {

                // Prepare the css properties for the "enter" animation of the mini player
                $('.twitch-mini-player').css({
                    opacity: '0'
                });

                // "Leaving" animation of the current page then "Enter" animation of the new page + Deleting the iframe of the twitch main player
                $activeWrapper.animate({
                    left: '600px',
                    opacity: '0'
                }, 500, function () {
                    $activeWrapper.css({
                        display: 'none'
                    });
                    $('.secondary-content').css({
                        display: 'flex'
                    });
                    $newActiveWrapper.css({
                        display: 'block'
                    });
                    $newActiveWrapper.animate({
                        opacity: '1',
                        top: '0'
                    }, 500);
                    $('#twitch-embed').remove();
                });

                // New "state" variable values + display mini player + "enter" animation of mini player
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $activeNav = $toActiveNav;
                    $activeWrapper = $newActiveWrapper;
                    $('.twitch-mini-player').append(twitchPlayerSnippet);

                    // calling a function declared somewhere else in the script
                    displayTwitch();
                    $('#content').css({
                        'overflow': 'visible'
                    });
                    $('.twitch-mini-player').delay(250).animate({
                        opacity: '1'
                    });
                }, 1050);

            // If we were already in a secondary content
            } else {

                //pretty much the same than earlier but without main player and mini player modifications
                $activeWrapper.animate({
                    left: '600px',
                    opacity: '0'
                }, 500, function () {
                    $activeWrapper.css({
                        display: 'none'
                    });
                    $newActiveWrapper.css({
                        display: 'block'
                    });
                    $newActiveWrapper.animate({
                        opacity: '1',
                        top: '0'
                    }, 500);
                });

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $activeNav = $toActiveNav;
                    $activeWrapper = $newActiveWrapper;
                    $('#content').css({
                        'overflow': 'visible'
                    });
                }, 1050);
            }
        }
    }
```

There is 3 other scripts like this one for the other pages.

So here is the thing, if you click quickly on one secondary content's nav button then another, both pages are getting displayed spliting the website content frame in 2 50% width frames.

I've been searching for what cause this problem for a few days but I really can't figure it out...

I know all of this is really sub optimal, but it's the "purpose" of this website, start from very basic knowledge and upgrade it step by step while learning new things.

Comment: It would be helpful to see more of your code, but my initial suspicion is that you are using `setTimeout` to set the active variables and not canceling the timeouts if another nav event occurs. Try using `cancelTimeout` and keeping a reference to the current timeout and see if that helps in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll check it after work this evening. You have the link of the website in the post (ponceriv.fr) , you can check the full script with the dev tools, I thought putting the whole script wouldn't be relevant as it's 4 conditions blocks like this one (for the 4 pages). But I can rehost it on jsfiddle if you tell me it's better :)